# what is [] operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators

I don't get it that [] is an operator in ruby. I was wondering that if `[]` is an operator then what are these parenthesis `{} & ()`. Are these also operators?

What I know is that these symbols are used by the language parser for interpreting/compiling code.

Comment: One way of looking at it is that `foo[i]` is just syntactic sugar for something like `foo.index(i)`. In the end it's not particularly different from `a + b` being syntactic sugar for `sum(a, b)`. (edit: I know technically it isn't the case in Ruby, but speaking purely on a conceptual level, the operators are functions.)

Comment: thanks @Arkku! 
`+` is operator and method as well, as `a + b` same as that of `a.+(b)`. According to 

ruby operators are methods 
http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/operators/methods.html

But I don't get details for these parenthesis `[]`

Comment: What is your definition of "operator"?

Comment: I don't think there is that much to "get" about `[]` beyond the fact that the operand is placed in between the `[]` to get a nicer (and more traditional) syntax, i.e., it could have been made as an infix operator `arr [] i` but it's instead `arr[i]`. The principle is the same.

Comment: As a thought exercise, let's say you were able to define arbitrary operators similar to `[]`. You could then have `\/` operator that would be called as `foo\i/`. But deep down it would just be a method on `foo` that takes `i` as an argument.

Comment: BTW note that the `.` in `obj.method(arg)` is, in a sense, also just there to get a nicer syntax… It could just as well have been `method(obj, arg)`. So, you could also argue that `arr[i]` could be written `index(arr, i)`. (It can't in Ruby, but again conceptually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you're talking about array literals or those brackets used for getting or assigning values from/to arrays or hashes.

As a literal, `[]` is just an array literal, shorthand for writing `Array.new`. You also asked about `{}`, which is a hash literal, i.e. shorthand for writing `Hash.new`. Parentheses are *not* literals (or 'operators' for that matter) – they're used to group things.

As an 'operator' for getting or assigning values, as others have pointed out in the comments, `[]` isn't special or conceptually different from other 'operators'.

In the same way `2 + 3` is sugar for writing `2.+(3)`, writing `array[0]` is sugar for writing `array.[](0)`.

The reason this works is that arrays have a method that's literally called `[]`. You can find it by getting all the methods on an array:

```rb
[].methods
# => long array including :[] (and also :[]=, by the way, for assignments)
```

Note that the brackets in `[].methods` are an array literal, *not* an 'operator'.

I haven't looked at the implementation of any Ruby interpreters, but my guess is they see something like `array[0]` and convert it to `array.[](0)` (or at least they treat it as such). That's why this kind of sugar syntax works and looks like 'operators' even though it's all methods under the hood.